# updateOne nested Array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a group collection that has the array `order` that contains ids.
I would like to use `updateOne` to set multiple items in that order array.

I tried this which updates one value in the array:

```
db.groups.updateOne({
    _id: '831e0572-0f04-4d84-b1cf-64ffa9a12199'
  },
  {$set: {'order.0': 'b6386841-2ff7-4d90-af5d-7499dd49ca4b'}}
)
```

That correctly updates (or sets) the array value with index 0.

However, I want to set more array values and updateOne also supports a pipeline so I tried this:

```
db.slides.updateOne({
    _id: '831e0572-0f04-4d84-b1cf-64ffa9a12199'
  },
  [
    {$set: {'order.0': 'b6386841-2ff7-4d90-af5d-7499dd49ca4b1'}}
  ]
)
```

This does NOTHING if the order array is empty. But if it's not, it replaces every element in the order array with an object `{ 0: 'b6386841-2ff7-4d90-af5d-7499dd49ca4b1' }`.
I don't understand that behavior.

In the optimal case I would just do

```
db.slides.updateOne({
    _id: '831e0572-0f04-4d84-b1cf-64ffa9a12199'
  },
  [
    {$set: {'order.0': 'b6386841-2ff7-4d90-af5d-7499dd49ca4b1'}},
    {$set: {'order.1': 'otherid'}},
    {$set: {'order.2': 'anotherone'}},
  ]
)
```

And that would just update the order array with the values.

What is happening here and how can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: if you want to update more than one order ids at once, you don't need to use aggregation pipeline, just add key value pair after zero index in same `$set`, see `{ $set: { 'order.0': 'id1', 'order.1': 'id2' } }` [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/).

Comment: @turivishal Yes I could do that. As a matter of fact, I have all those updates in an array and in order to merge them to one update I would need to write logic that mongodb aleady performs in its optimization stage. In any case, whatever happens now, makes zero sense to me and it should work

Comment: in aggregation pipeline the meaning of `$set` is projection in root level properties, it will not update array element by position. so $set will perform dirrerently in both the ways.

Comment: @turivishal I am aware that pipeline $set is different. However, obviously it can update sub properties. Why not by array index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update by index position in the array is only supported in regular update queries, but not in aggregation queries,

They have explained this feature in regular update query [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays) operator documentation, but not it [aggregation $set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/).

The correct implementation in regular update query:

```
db.slides.updateOne({
    _id: '831e0572-0f04-4d84-b1cf-64ffa9a12199'
  },
  {
    $set: {
      'order.0': 'b6386841-2ff7-4d90-af5d-7499dd49ca4b1',
      'order.1': 'otherid',
      'order.2': 'anotherone'
    }
  }
)
```

If you are looking for only an aggregation query, it is totally long process than the above regular update query, i don't recommend that way instead, you can format your input in your client-side language and use regular query.

Comment: I don't get why updating multiple values with multiple sets is fine. Even setting multiple nested properties. But when it comes to arrays it's a problem all of a sudden. It's just another nested prop which happens to end with a numeric key. Guess I have to do all the work and merge the updates...

Comment: They have not mentioned why it is not supported in update with aggregation in documentation, but as per the documentation of aggregation $set is just for projection and alternate for $addFields and $project stage, and i think this is a support a feature level question, you need to ask to mongodb developers in [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/) or [mongodb community forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `aggregation` framework, try this (you will have to pass array of indexes and array of updated values separately):

- `$map` and `$range` to iterate over the `order` array by indexes
- `$cond` and `$arrayElemAt` to check if the current index is in the array of indexes that has to be updates. If it is, update it with the same index from the array of new values. If it is not, keep the current value.

**NOTE**: This will work only if the array of indexes that you want to update starts from 0 and goes up (as in your example).

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: '831e0572-0f04-4d84-b1cf-64ffa9a12199'
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "order": {
        "$map": {
          input: {
            $range: [
              0,
              {
                $size: "$order"
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $in: [
                  "$$this",
                  [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2
                  ]
                ]
              },
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  [
                    "b6386841-2ff7-4d90-af5d-7499dd49ca4b1",
                    "otherid",
                    "anotherone"
                  ],
                  "$$this"
                ]
              },
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$order",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/P4irM9Ouyza

Comment: See my first comment on the question. I need a solution with pipeline

Comment: I updated my answer. Check if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think it will work. My aggregation could also contain sets on other elements and not just the array e.g. `$set: { otherfield: 6 }`. I appreciate the effort, though

Comment: But you can also add `$set` to other fields. You can do that in the same stage actually.

Comment: Yes but I would need to know where I am updating an array and where I am just updating any other (nested) prop

Comment: I don't get it. You can independently update other nested fields. I updated working example so you can check it.

Comment: I have an array and every element has one update step which updates any nested property. They are not sorted. Your solution requires to figure this out before and when I already did that, I could just merge it into one set statement anyway